# Какое название у переменной отвечающей за акции и как вообще посмотреть список переменных?

Tags: переменные, wordpress

Доброго всем дня
Вижу WordPress 30 минут как изнутри.
Вижу переменную

> 

Она выводит новости.
меняю

> 

на

> 

или на

> 

И ни чего не происходит.
Вопрос:

### Какое название у переменной отвечающей за акции и как вообще посмотреть список переменных в WoedPress?

Или как вывести эту ктегорию новостей?
Если есть переменная News, то в неё входит категория Actions
Исходя из структуры WordPress'а
То как из данной =nvl($news['contents']) переменной вытащить категорию "Акции"?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Можно я позанудствую: не приходило в голову заглянуть в документацию? Это не только WP касается, кстати, а вообще любого инструмента. Сначала читать доки/маны, потом уже тянуть руки к клавиатуре. В общем, вам сюда:

- [WordPeress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/)
- [WordPress Codex на русском](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0)
- [Документация для разработчика WordPress на русском](http://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)
- [WordPress Developer Documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Developer_Documentation) (более полная, чем на русском)
- [WordPress Code Reference](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/)

Comment: @klopp, я бы добавил еще ссылку на документацию на русском языке, предвосхищая возможную просьбу пользователя.

Comment: На русском только сам Codex вроде бы, добавил.

P.S. А, не, не только. Но английская всё равно полней.

Comment: to @klopp:  
Всё бы хорошо, только вот ни один нормальный в мире человек не сможет выучить все CMS.  
А сайт видоизменить от стандарта или сделанного на заказ, сейчас любая бизнес-блондинка желает.
Неужели стоит набирать специалистов по каждой распространённой CMS?  
Или же всем давать отказ, так как у них CMS не Drupal?
---
P.S. вот и пошёл самым примитивным путём - сделал редирект главной, на туда, куда просили. (Хорошо хоть не фреймом.)

Comment: @I_CaR, изучать-то прям зачем. Ознакомиться с нужными местами в доках.

Answer (score 1):

В оригинальном WP нету таких переменных nvl($news['contents']);. Скорее всего вы смотрите какой то WP framework. И как можно наобум менять, если вы даже не знаете что за переменные?

Comment: меняю исходя из опыта.  
Новости они "news", акции по логике "actions"  
Или же есть языки программирования высокого уровня без логики?

Comment: @I_CaR, WP в душе не знает, что у вас там, для него это называется таксономии. Для плагина/темы/фреймворка может и по-другому называться.